# onChange last character not removes in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

Here I have one input field this input field is number type So i make validation on this input field of number type see in code(it allows only numbers) it works perfectly but after typing some integers and when I go to make empty input field it is not removes last one character in input field how to remove that also ?

```
<Input
  name='monthlyPrice'
  type='number'            
  value={this.state.monthlyPrice}
  onChange={this.onInputChangeValue}
/>

onInputChangeValue(e){
  if(e.target.value.match(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/)) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your `||` back in from your previous question:

```
<Input
  name='monthlyPrice'
  type='number'            
  value={this.state.monthlyPrice}
  onChange={this.onInputChangeValue}
/>

onInputChangeValue(e){
  if(e.target.value == "" || e.target.value.match(/^[1-9]\d*\.?\d*$/)) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
}
```

**Note:** This would still require you to check before the form is submitted, as this would allow them to leave the field ending in a `.` character. You could also do this in an `onBlur` if you wanted to. The regex to test for this would be `^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?$`

**Note 2:** This regex is based on OP's first question which required the first digit to be 1-9

Comment: the regex fails for the same reason I stated in my comments on your last question. the `\.` is not optional, so you can't have a string which ends in `.` (for example as you're typing or as you're deleting the numbers. This causes your regex to fail and you can never delete beyond the `.` or add one in as you're typing - only works if you're deleting the whole text or pasting a value in.

Comment: So what is solution can you help me proper regex so I can stop to allow 'E, e, -, +' and multiple dots and onchange time I can make whole input field also

Comment: my regex on your previous question would allow you to continue typing this. I'll update my answer with my regex. However you'll ALSO need to validate before submit to ensure they've entered the number correctly (that it doesn't end on a `.`). I'll include this in the answer

Comment: u give same regex see in my question

Answer (score 0):

you can use useRef for fetching values and onChange event for triggering any function if you need

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and what worked for me is to simply use `defaultValue` instead of `value` in your

Answer (score -2):

I guess you can reset the state before setting it to the new value.

```
onInputChangeValue(e){
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: "" }, () => {
    if(e.target.value.match(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/)) {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, there's no guarantee that the blank set state will run before the other one. Consider changing this to functional setState, as those are run in the order they're declared. However this still causes an issue where if they user accidentally hits the wrong character it'll remove the input they've already entered, rather than just preventing entry.